# Display data from API to Custom Spinner using Retrofit2 Kotlin/Java

Tags: java, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, android-spinner

I have an API that have names and photos, i want to display it on my custom spinner using kotlin or java. I tried to write a code that is similar on implementing recycler view but it is not working. Please give me an idea or example how to do it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to separate your data from your ui.

In your data, you'll write all about your model, the API requests, etc.

In your presentation, you'll code about the view and you'll just have to call the functions that you coded in your data.

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Thank you for your response but i know what you mean and i know coding architecture. my problem is how to implement data from api to custom spinner.

Comment: the github you sent does not have a spinner example also lol.

Comment: It looks like you're the author of the linked article.  Please disclose your affiliation with your articles and videos, *in the answer*, for your posts not to be considered spam.  For more info please see [How not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: yes but I only posted it because I thought it could help, but as MaroonDre said, it doesn't have a spinner example so it is useless

Comment: @AsuncionGomez Posting it because you think it'll help isn't the problem:  Under Stack Exchange policy, you must disclose your affiliation or your post may be deleted.  If you think it's useless, you can just remove the link.